# How to make ATOM ide always as a python IDE?

Tags: atom-editor

Is there anyway to have the ATOM ide always run python right from the start? I always have to write something then save, then run. Is there anyway to simple have to where I open up Atom, type some python code and hit right?

Thank you

Comment: If Atom 'sees' the .py extension on your file name it should be in python-mode.

Comment: You can install the default-language package and set the language in its settings to `python`. https://atom.io/packages/default-language